# How to set background-image position above the element?

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-position

I have an element (a button) that i want to have 2 background images.
one is a gradient and i want the other to position above the button.
How do i do that?

Is there some way i can add something simillar to margin-top: -20px; or something like that?

Comment: Well. found my answer here :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053950/css-background-image-positioning-negative-position

Comment: Kinda new here, how do i do that?

Comment: You can either hit close under your question or add the answer to your question below and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using :before psuedo

for example:

```
  .box:before{
       content:url(icon_neutral.png);
       display:block;
       position:relative;
       top: -30px;
  }
```

according to gagarine's solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053950/css-background-image-positioning-negative-position):

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .modalBackground
    {
        background-image:url('image/img2.jpg');
        background-repeat:repeat-x  ;

        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
  </style>
```