# CSS negative right background position

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I know I can set a negative left position on a background image like this:

```
#element {
    background: url(image.png) -20px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

That'll position the background image 20px to the left of the left edge of `#element`, regardless of `#element`'s width.

But is there any way to set a negative *right* position, *without* giving `#element` a fixed width (and then just setting a high positive left value)?

Comment: In other words, position the image N px to the left of the right edge? Not possible AFAIK.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's simply not true that this effect is impossible to obtain through simple CSS. There is no need to complicate your mark-up with unnecessary pseudo elements or multiple divs.

You can use the "calc" function in CSS to make the browser calculate 100% of the containers width and then add your negative margin to that like so (remember to add your negative margin to the 100% *not* subtract it):

```
background-position: calc(100% + 20px) 0;
```

Or if you prefer your mark-up in short-hand format:

```
background: url("image.png") calc(100% + 20px) 0 no-repeat;
```

This will position your background-image 100% (hereby obtaining the same effect as using *background-position: right*) from the left side of its container and by adding the 20px to that, you will obtain your negative right margin.

You can see a demo of how the function behaves in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58u665fe/

The "calc" function is supported by most major browsers, though support for IE9< lacks in certain cases. You can read more about which browsers support this function on http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc.

Answer (score 3):

What you're wanting to do is not possible in the way you want to do it.

A fix might be to create a parent div with a `position: relative;` attribute and then z-index another div behing a div that holds your content.

```
<style>
    #parent {
        position: relative; 
    }
    #background {
        background: url(img.png) top left no-repeat;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -20px;
    }
    #content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>


<div id="parent">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: That's clever! But don't you mean `right: -20px` for `#background` instead of `left: -20px`?

Comment: It just depends on where you want it to display.  If I was going by the question, it would actually be `top: -20px; left: 0px;` as the first value listed is the vertical position and the second is horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to achieve this without changing your markup:

using the :after pseudo-selector you can add an image to the right of any block although is not the same as an actual css background

so you can do:

```
#element {
  position: relative;
}
#element:after{
  content: "";
  background: transparent url(image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px /*add height of your image here*/ 
  width: 50px /*add width of your image here*/
  z-index: 1;  
}
#element *{
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 2; /*this makes sure all the "background image" doesn't sit above the elements*/  
}
```

Comment: This advise is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8439392/267197), however I would prefer the later one (`content: url(...); display:block;`) as it does not require to specify `width` and `height`.