# Input field with background img outside of input

Tags: css, input

Setup: I cannot change anything outside of the CSS, I can ask to change but It would be easier if this can be done in HTML.  Other than that I will have to create a jQuery snippet and see if the developer will include it.

Problem: i need this image(RED INCORRECT IMAGE) to be to the right of my input field, currently it will only stay inside of the input field.

[image]

Solutions attempted.

```
.passwordMismatch {
    background: url("layout/pw_error_tooltip.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-color: red !important;
    border-width: 2px !important;
}
```

[image]

I also tried knowing this wouldnt work as well.

```
.passwordMismatch:after {
    background: url("layout/pw_error_tooltip.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 40px;
    padding-right: 200px;
}
```

Appreciate any help in solving this.
http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/DpQXR/

---

I appreciate everyones responses unfortunately this is a deadend and the solutions offered are all pretty much what I already anticipated. Thank you.

Comment: You want to get effect like on first image, without any html/js changes. Am i right?

Comment: well kind a logic as the image is displayed as background image, isnt it?

Comment: What is the parent box of the `.passwordMismatch` element? Is it inside an input tag? That'd be really weird. Could you share some code?

Comment: @Tyblitz The parent tag is a LI, which I have considered asking to have the .passwordMissmatch put on that, the input field currently has .passwordMissmatch.

Comment: @Kasyx yes, without any, I am currently testing using :after with content: url(imglink); display:block; position:relative; to see if I can get any results, so far none.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the :after pseudo selector on a form element.

So just add a element after and position it from the left, something like:

```
.passwordMistmatchMessage {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background: url("https://selfservice.ennis.com/layout/pw_error_tooltip.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-color: red !important;
    border-width: 2px !important;
    width: 176px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 8px;
}
```

... and add the element using jQuery ...

```
$(".passwordMismatch").after("<span class='passwordMistmatchMessage'></span>");
```

@see http://jsfiddle.net/DpQXR/2/

Comment: I got the idea for using :after from this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053950/css-background-image-positioning-negative-position what I intend on doing is having the developer move the .passwordMissmatch to the adjacent parent element LI

Answer (score 1):

[You can't have a background image going outside of elements boundaries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056410/can-background-image-extend-beyond-divs-borders)

What I'd do is create a `<span>` element which floats next to the input and has the red balloon background. Show it when needed, hide it when not.

Comment: I really wanted to avoid adding any further HTML, jQuery is on the board of possibilities currently, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<label>` as a hook for the pseudo element. Positioning could be a little awkward, but anyhow, worth a try:

http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/JDIix

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
label.new {position: relative; display: block;}

label:after {
    content: " ";
    background: url("https://selfservice.ennis.com/layout/pw_error_tooltip.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
    top: 100%;
    height: 30px; 
    width: 176px;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #87888A;
    color: #888888;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 27px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<label for="newpassword1" class="new">New Password:</label>
<input type="password" onblur="com_micrlink_passwordValidate()" name="Password1" class="Password passwordMismatch" id="newpassword1">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that .passwordMissmatch is a dynamic class that only appears if you have not put the information correctly into the field. I think this is going to end up having to be changed in order to use the graphic. Thank you though. +1

Comment: Yes, of course, I should have thought of that. In these situations, it's not really practical to be constrained to CSS alone, when modifying the HTML/JS would make life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

For creating snippet for jQuery may be better a route is this [solutions](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) . You can to change the background image on yours